# How to set the font of only the selected child inside my mdiParent

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm relatively new to C#, as my background is actually java.

I'm creating a little Windows Forms app similar to notepad, only I'm using a MDIContainer-parent as the base of my app and various children-windows as the 'pages'.
What I'm trying to do is to set the font of only the selected child form from my FontDialog (activated from a MenuBar on the parent window). I have managed to get it to set the font of all the child forms together, but obviously that's not ideal.
Thanks, help is appreciated. :)

*Note: I have not included any code, as I don't have anything relevant*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Form.ActiveMdiChild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activemdichild.aspx) to get the currently active child form.

On the other hand, a better approach might be to create child-form-specific menu items on the child form itself, and then [merge these items into the main menu strip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404319.aspx). This way, whenever you activate a child form, it will be responsible for handling its own commands.